# SonarQube Scanner doesn't use both global or specific proxy settings

Tags: docker, jenkins, proxy, sonarqube-scan

We're using sonar scanner in our Jenkins pipeline to scan our code in a JNLP slave. 
Both Sonarscanner and SonarQube are running in Docker containers in Openshift.
Our SonarQube server is behind a proxy without authentication.
Sonar scanner doesn't read any proxy information we submit to it through either -D http.ProxyHost in start command or in the configuration file. There is no way to reach our Sonarqube server behind the proxy. Could you help us figure out what to do?

I tried all ways to fix it but nothing works:

- Passing -D https.ProxyHost -D https.ProxyPort (without http:// header)
- putting them into sonar-scanner.properties
- Passing proxy values in environment variables HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, JAVA_OPTS...
  Doing a curl to the SonarQube server works -> Firewall is ok, connectivity is ok.

I couldn't find any issues tracker regarding this project in Github and the Jira tracker is closed to submitting new issues.

Has anyone encountered the same issue? There is another question related to this but no answer have been given: [SonarQube scanner can't connect to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632245/sonarqube-scanner-cant-connect-to-server)

Thanks,

Lain92

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and the way I found to fix this is using an environment variable.

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=<PROXY> -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=<PROXY> -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=\"localhost|127.0.0.1\""
```

Note that "-Dhttp.proxyHost" does not have space between D and http.proxy.

Comment: Ozahata, where did you set this?

Comment: It will depend on the way you implement. It can be in the Jenkinsfile, when you initialize the variables or in a batch file that Jenkinsfile calls.